# Exchanging desktop publishing files between my Mac an office pc

Tags: mac

I have a Mac notebook, running Microsoft 365 for Mac which does not include Microsoft Publisher.  Our office uses pc's and Microsoft Publisher to create our brochures, flyers, and bulletins.  We each need to be able to read and edit the files.

Is there any way we can accomplish this exchange of pub files?  The answers I've read in response to similar questions address 1) using other software that is specifically for Mac, 2) creating PDF files in publisher that can be imported into my Mac app (but doen't tell if I can export the files so that the pc can import and edit), or 3) using the limited option of publishing layout in word.

Both the Mac and PCs need full functionality.  Any suggestions?

Comment: If you have to be able to work seriously with Publisher files on a Mac, I think the only real option is to run Windows on with Windows Office installed.

Comment: I've looked into this periodically since Office 2003. The answer is always the same: Don't do it. Publisher use its own file format that isn't compatible with anything else, and not popular enough for 3rd-parties to build cross-app compatibility. Your best option, if you MUST keep using Publisher, is to install it in a virtual machine (either [WINE](https://winehq.org/)/[Crossover](https://www.codeweavers.com/), or [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/)/[VMWare Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion)). Check compatibility before going too far in one direction.